# clang scan-build Redhat installation

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, jenkins-plugins, scan-build

I've installed `clang-3.4.2-7.el7.x86_64.rpm` on RHEL 7 and it came with llvm, but i couldn't find the scan-build utility.

I have already installed gcc and cmake and all other tools that are mentioned [here](http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html#software) But unfortunately i can't execute the scan-build commands.

BTW, I want to integrate it with [Clang Scan-Build Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Clang+Scan-Build+Plugin).

Am I missing something in the configuration?

Answer (score 5):

It's in the package **clang-analyzer**

Answer (score 1):

Clang analyzer doesn't get installed by default, to install it with the current version of LLVM 6.0 run:

`yum install llvm-toolset-6.0-clang-analyzer`

You may also want to install `llvm-toolset-6.0-clang-tools-extra`.

[How to install Clang/LLVM 6 on RHEL](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2019/03/05/yum-install-gcc-8-clang-6/) has this and other details.